# SQL conditional Recursive query to assign item quantity to multiple company

Tags: database, postgresql, left-join, case, recursive-query

I Have two tables t1 and t2 . t1 contains excess data of any item for any company while table t2 contains required data for any item for that company .

Now, problem is for a single item there are multiple company which has excess qty and similarly for that single item there are multiple company which required that item.

Now, we can set the priority that the company which has most qty for any item will be given priority 1 for transferring qty and similarly the company which has most qty required for that particular item will be given priority 1 for receiving.

** Create table script**
** t1** :-

```
CREATE TABLE t1 
(
    company id 1    VARCHAR(512),
    item id VARCHAR(512),
    excess qty  INT
);

INSERT INTO t1 (company id 1, item id, excess qty) VALUES ('3', 'a', '30');
INSERT INTO t1 (company id 1, item id, excess qty) VALUES ('2', 'a', '25');
INSERT INTO t1 (company id 1, item id, excess qty) VALUES ('1', 'a', '10');
INSERT INTO t1 (company id 1, item id, excess qty) VALUES ('1', 'b', '15');
INSERT INTO t1 (company id 1, item id, excess qty) VALUES ('2', 'b', '10');
INSERT INTO t1 (company id 1, item id, excess qty) VALUES ('3', 'b', '10');
INSERT INTO t1 (company id 1, item id, excess qty) VALUES ('1', 'c', '20');
INSERT INTO t1 (company id 1, item id, excess qty) VALUES ('3', 'c', '15');
INSERT INTO t1 (company id 1, item id, excess qty) VALUES ('3', 'd', '10');
INSERT INTO t1 (company id 1, item id, excess qty) VALUES ('2', 'd', '5');
```

** t2 **

```
CREATE TABLE t2 
(
    company id 2    INT,
    item id VARCHAR(512),
    required qty    INT
);

INSERT INTO t2 (company id 2, item id, required qty) VALUES ('4', 'a', '25');
INSERT INTO t2 (company id 2, item id, required qty) VALUES ('4', 'b', '10');
INSERT INTO t2 (company id 2, item id, required qty) VALUES ('4', 'c', '15');
INSERT INTO t2 (company id 2, item id, required qty) VALUES ('5', 'a', '20');
INSERT INTO t2 (company id 2, item id, required qty) VALUES ('5', 'b', '5');
INSERT INTO t2 (company id 2, item id, required qty) VALUES ('5', 'c', '40');
INSERT INTO t2 (company id 2, item id, required qty) VALUES ('5', 'd', '10');
```

** Sample data**

** t1**

| company id 1 | item id | excess qty |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 3 | a | 30 |
| 2 | a | 25 |
| 1 | a | 10 |
| 1 | b | 15 |
| 2 | b | 10 |
| 3 | b | 10 |
| 1 | c | 20 |
| 3 | c | 15 |
| 3 | d | 10 |
| 2 | d | 5 |

** t2 **

| company id 2 | item id | required qty |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 4 | a | 25 |
| 5 | a | 20 |
| 4 | b | 10 |
| 5 | b | 5 |
| 5 | c | 40 |
| 4 | c | 15 |
| 5 | d | 10 |

** Expected Output **

| company id 2 | item id | required qty | company id 1 | transfer qty 1 | remain qty |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 4 | a | 25 | 3 | 25 | 5 |
| 5 | a | 20 | 2 | a | 5 |
| 4 | b | 10 | 1 | 10 | 5 |
| 5 | b | 5 | 1 | 5 | 0 |
| 5 | c | 40 | 1 | 20 | -20 |
| 5 | c | 20 | 3 | 15 | -5 |
| 4 | c | 15 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 5 | d | 10 | 3 | 10 | 0 |

** example**
ex 1 :- In table t2-for item id a , max required qty is 25 for company id 4
and in table t1 - for item id a max qty available is 30 for company id 3
so , from this 30 , 25 will be transferred and 5 will remain. Now if this remaining qty is enough to fulfil the requirement of 2nd company requirement then we will send from here otherwise will look for 2nd excess qty company

and

if the max requirement is greater than the maximum excess qty available , case where remaining qty is negative then the remaining qty can be fulfil by the 2nd excess qty company and so (see data of item id c).

** What I have tried**
I have tried by assigning rank which has excess qty and has excess requirement but in this case I will not get the required output.

** my query**

```
with t1 as 
(select * , row_number() over(partition by company id 1 order by excess qty desc) as rn1
from t1
)
,t2 as 
(
select * , row_number() over(partition by company id 2 order by required qty desc) as rn2
from t2
)
select * from t2
left join t1 on t1.item_id=t2.item_id and t1.rn1=t2.rn2
```

Please help, Thanks.